# How to Roll back original width for disabled input after cursor pass over?

Tags: jquery, blur, mousemove

How do I roll back to original width this disabled input after cursor pass over, I already tried with.blur but is not working.

```
   $('input[readonly]').mousemove(function(){
       if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
                $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
                $(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
                $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
              }
    });
```

Please See the Below Example :-
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/188/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure for what you need this but you can try focus:

```
$('input').focus(function(){
if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
$(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
$(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
$(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
}
}).blur(function(){ /* lookup the original width */
var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
$(this).animate({
width: w
}, 'slow');
$(this).parent().removeClass('cooling');
});
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/192/

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead.

```
var w;
$('input[readonly]').mouseenter(function(){
       if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
               w =   $(this).css('width');
                $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
                $(this).animate({width: 300}, 'slow');
                $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
              }
    });
$('input[readonly]').mouseleave(function(){
       if ($(this).val().length > 20) {
                $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
                $(this).animate({width: w}, 'slow');
                $(this).parent().addClass('cooling');
              }
    });
```

You might want to remove cooling class in mouseleave?

Working sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/DCjYA/189/